# Matplotlib imshow colormap not covering full dynamic range of data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to produce colormaps of `numpy` arrays with large dynamic ranges. To that end, I've tried using `imshow` from `matplotlib.pyplot`, but there appears to be a problem with the colormap.

Specifically, every value in the array below a certain threshold is plotted as the same color as the minimum value in the array.

Below is a minimal working example. I produce an array containing values from 1e-4 to 1e+20, but in `imshow` all cells containing values less than 1e+3 appear to be set equal to 1e-4. However, there is no such issue using `pcolormesh`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

# 2d (5x5) array with large dynamic range: 1e-4, 1e-3, ..., 1e+20
a = np.logspace(-4, 20, num=25).reshape(5, 5)

# imshow producing wrong image
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(a, norm=LogNorm(), origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig("imshow_broken.png")

# pcolormesh producing correct image
fig = plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(a, norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig("pcolormesh_working.png")
```

I'm using `matplotlib` version 2.1.2, but the problem seems to disappear on older versions, e.g. 1.5.3, perhaps suggesting a bug in recent `matplotlib` versions.

`imshow`:
[image: imshow_broken]

`pcolormesh`:
[image: pcolormesh_working]

Comment: this example produces the same (incorrect) output in version 2.2.2 (latest stable at time of writing)

Comment: In addition to choosing to use `pcolormesh` to visualize your data, you can use `imshow`, but with `interpolation_stage='rgba'` rather than the default `interpolation_stage='data'`. When this is set to 'data' (the default), apparently the data goes through a scaling process intended to prevent agg (see matplotlib backends) from clipping the extremes of your data. This scaling process wrecks this sort of exponential data though. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19748 for more detail and discussion.