# Colors not displayed correctly when wide range of values is plotted with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, imshow

If the range of values plotted with the `imshow` function of matplotlib is large (and a logarithmic normalization is necessary), it seems some values are not plotted with the correct color, that is, the color you would expect from looking at the colorbar. I ran into this problem while working on some larger dataset, but the code below should provide a minimal example, which produces this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK6iM.png) for me.

Some intermediate values (10 and 1e-2) are, unexpectedly, given the same color as the lowest value (1e-10) in the test data. If instead of 10, 100 is plotted, the 'right' color is displayed. The problem also disappears if the maximum value (1e19) is lowered to 1e15, for example, but increasing the lowest value doesn't have the same effect.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

TestGrid = np.array([[1e19, 10], [1e-2, 1e-10]])
LogNorm = colors.LogNorm(TestGrid.min(), TestGrid.max())

img = plt.imshow(TestGrid, norm=LogNorm, cmap='plasma')

plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

To isolate the problem, I have tried checking what the `LogNorm` function returns, for one of the intermediate values:

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
print(cmap(LogNorm(10), bytes=True)) #prints (170, 36, 148, 255)
```

This seems to give the same color as you would expect from the colorbar and the problem thus appears to be with the `imshow` or `colorbar` function.

I also tried using `pcolor` instead of `imshow`, and this actually gives the expected result. However, this issue still puzzles me, and I hope someone can tell me what's going wrong.

I am using python 3.6 and matplotlib 3.1, if that's important.

Comment: Similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879082/matplotlib-imshow-colormap-not-covering-full-dynamic-range-of-data), unfortunately without answer.

Comment: A workaround, apart from using `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` is `plt.imshow(np.log(TestGrid), cmap='plasma');
plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='plasma', norm=LogNorm))`, although this will show the log values in the statusbar while hovering over the pixels.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for your answer! That old post indeed describes the same problem. Your workaround works well for me too.